# Remotely Calling WebService via Ajax (ASP.NET)

Tags: .net, ajax, web-services, asmx, access-control

**CLIENT - AJAX**

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://www.site.com/Service.asmx/Method',
        data: "{ 'user': 'sampleuser', 'pass': '123456' }",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function (result) {
            alert("result: '" + result+ "'");
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert("error: '" + e + "'");
        }
    });
```

**SERVER - GLOBAL.ASAX**

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");    
    // HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://AllowedDomain.com");
}
```

**SERVER - WEB.CONFIG**

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Authorization" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

**SERVER - THE SERVICE - C#**

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string Method(string user, string pass)
{
    // logic
}
```

What happens is that when the ajax is called, it goes straight to the success callback with result = null. This error comes up on the debugger:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.site.com/Service.asmx/Method.
Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Comment: What version of IIS are you using?

Comment: Also can you catch the actual request/response and check that the headers are actually being added?

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing **url** to **origin** in the Ajax call.